# When I link 2 textboxes, word automatically keeps paragraphs together

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I am trying to create a document with columns in a textbox, the only way to do that seems to be to create multiple textboxes & link them. The problem is that Word automatically keeps paragraphs together & won't let me start a paragraph in one textbox & overflow it in the next one. it just moves the whole paragraph to the next textbox.
[image: connected Textboxes]
These 2 textboxes are linked and the bottom margin is 0.1cm (as you can see in the next pic) but I end up with this gap at the bottom of the textbox, & I want the text to flow.

My Format shape pop up box looks like this.

[image: Format shape pop up box]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screen shot of what you are seeing so we better understand the problem space.

Answer (score 0):

To link in Word multiple text boxes side-by-side, so allowing
text to freely flow from the left text box to the neighboring right,
do this:

- Place the two text boxes next to each other and sized correctly
- Right-click on the left text box
- In the Context menu choose "Create Text Box Link".
  The mouse pointer will change to a upright cup when located
  in the clicked text box.
- Move the mouse pointer to the right text box and it will change
  to a pouring cup (signifying text overflow into that text box)
- Click in the right column. The mouse pointer returns to normal.

The two text boxes are now linked.

References :

- [Columns within Text Boxes](https://word.tips.net/T001539_Columns_within_Text_Boxes.html)
- [Create columns of text in a text box or shape](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-columns-of-text-in-a-text-box-or-shape-848a86fd-dc46-4b16-a619-2ad0fcb465ba)
  (for Excel and PowerPoint)

Comment: I think the OP's issue is they want the text in one text box to flow freely between text in a separate text box like in publishing apps like Pagemaker and MS Publisher.  They probably have borders around the text boxes or something.  Can the columns in one be linked to another to allow free text flow?

Comment: @BlindSpots: If that's the case, I don't know of a solution.

Comment: @harrymc: I added a pic of the pop up box

Comment: Seems like Word 2016 doesn't have the COLUMNS button.

Comment: The source you're quoting is talking about Excel and PowerPoint as stated clearly at the top of the article

Comment: @ES: That's right! Just checked and Word 365 also doesn't have the COLUMNS button. I'll delete my answer soon. Message for the poster : The answer is negative, I don't know of a solution and I'm not sure that one exists.

Comment: @ES: I managed to find how to do that and rewrote my answer.

Comment: @harrymc: +Thanx, but as I wrote in my question I already did that. The problem is that it will always move the whole paragraph to the next text box instead of starting it in the the first & continuing in the 2nd, leaving me with empty spaces at the bottom of the text box.